# Elasticsearch Array Comparison

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm new to elasticsearch, so be kind.

I'm trying to store and query data, which is tagged with N number of tags.  I want to compare a search query array with the stored array and return the results in order of which items match the most tags.

Dataset example:

```
{ name: "karl", tags: ["terrible", "programmer"] }
{ name: "bob", tags: ["awesome", "programmer"] }
```

Query example, matching both people:

```
query: { tags: ["programmer"] }
result: [karl, bob]
```

And in this example, both are returned but bob scores high, because more tags were matched, **Karl is still shown though**, despite not matching on `awesome`.

```
query: { tags: ["programmer", "awesome"] }
result: [bob, karl]
```

The closet I have got is this, however it doesn't seem to score bob higher than karl

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "tags": "programmer" } },
        { "match": { "tags": "awesome" } }
       ],
      "minimum_number_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Would love some support :-)
Thanks!

Comment: have you found anything that could help?

Comment: Both queries in your question will give higher score to more matches. Can you add actual result of the query and  expected result

Answer (score 2):

It does score `bob` significantly higher than `karl`:
[image]

If you wanna match both of the tags, increase the `minimum` operator:
[image]

Which is essentially the same as a bunch of `bool-must`s:

```
GET karl/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "tags": "programmer"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "tags": "awesome"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have only the document that match both (or even more) tags, you need to use a must query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)
Your query looks like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "tags": "programmer" } },
        { "match": { "tags": "awesome" } }
       ]
    }
  }
}
```